Ubuntu 22.04: System shuts down after waking from sleep mode
So Currently i'm working in Awesome WM in ubuntu 22.04, on a Razor Blade 15 with 16GB ram, an intel i7 core cpu and an NVIDIA 1660 ti for the graphics card.
I've recently just picked up linux and i've been tailoring my system's interface to make it more to my liking, since i've started using awesome WM on the system whenever my system goes into sleep mode id wake it up just off pressing a key, and it would work normally for the first few moments. But then suddenly the screen would just go black and shut off.
Any help on this issue would be sick
tyy

What changes have you made ? Tailoring the system is of no help to someone trying to understand what you have done.

@David i installed and made a config file for alacritty, and changed my wallpaper with nitrogen. That's about as far as i gotten at the moment. everything else on my system is pretty much stock..
